# Move from a xib file to a viewcontroller in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have a tableviewcell xib . Inside that tableviewcell i have a collectionviewcell, i want to navigate from the collectionviewcell to a viewconttoller using storyboard. Can anyone help me if possible? I have to write the code inside collectionview didselect method

Comment: yes its possible but depends upon the way you are using those things.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? I can only do it with presentviewcontroller  and that to making it as rootview controller

Comment: i need to understand the flow of the controller and how you are using the collection view delegates inside the cell class. it will help more if you post some code.

Comment: im having a collectionview inside a tableviewcell xib and I want to move to another viewcontroller when the collectionviewcell is clicked

Comment: have you tried using notifications?

Answer (score -1):

```
UIStoryboard *yourStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryboardName" bundle: nil];

UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[yourStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerID"];

[tableViewController presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: in your case it is tableViewController.

Comment: I dont have a tableviewcontroller , Im having xib file for tableviewcell

Comment: In which viewcontroller you have your collectionview didselect method ? You can use that viewcontroller.

Comment: I have the collectionview didselect method inside tableview class

Comment: Can you please post your code / link the source files ?